# Is it possible to get the line number of annotations from .class file?

Tags: java

I'm trying to get the line number of annotations from .class file, but I can get only the list of annotations, not the lines. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: did you mean annotation used in source code(.java file) that line number?

Comment: @user404 yes, IMO and obviously.

Comment: @OP, try with javassist

Comment: Hi, you can try with ASM or JavAssist apis to scan the .class file

Comment: Would you please explain why you need this info? It is really interesting to understand the use case. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I've got the log file and I've to remove the line (in the log file) if refers to the annotation. My input is the .class file

Comment: If I understand your use case, you have to scan (on annotation) to get the line numbers and remove all lines in the log file if it refers to that lines. Is it right?

Comment: Yes, it's right

Comment: the `.class` file only records line number for debugging purposes. Since you can't debug this metadata, you can only infer a line number which is it on or before. The only way to know is to read the original source.

Comment: I'm agree with Peter and I think that it's hard (difficult or impossible) to retrieve the lines of the annotations. But you said before that you have a log file, so I suppose that log refers to an exception ...  right?

Comment: Yes, in my error log, I've the stack trace that refers at line of annotation

Comment: I'm not sure, but can the annotation throw an exception?

Comment: I suggest you to post this question

Comment: Thanks, I added a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54145778/annotation-and-exception)

Answer (score 4):

Looking through the [Java Class File Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.16) it seems that for annotations no line number information is recorded.

Since the line number information is not present within the class file you cannot extract it from the class file.

Line numbers are only available for code segments: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.12

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java Decompiler. Follow this [JD GUI](http://jd.benow.ca/), download the jar file and run it, keep the class files you want to decompile in same place with the jd-gui jar's directory and you will find if any annotation is used in source code there.

Comment: As far as I know, to decompile a .class file is not right copy of original .java file, I mean that you cannot get the right line number ... you can try!

Comment: most probably(I did and forgot actually) it excludes the commented  codeblocks.